# Import variable from qdateedit into back end script

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have two scripts. On is called Reports and was created using pyqt4 designer and translated into a .py file. The other is called Renewals. This the back end script that contains a function called run_renewals, which is called upon in the Reports file.

Below is the relevant code from Reports.py (GUI file)

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from Renewals import run_renewals
import pandas as pd
import sys

self.Go = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
self.Go.clicked.connect(run_renewals)
self.Go.clicked.connect(self.on_Go_clicked)
self.Go.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Go"))

self.As_of_Date = QtGui.QDateEdit(Form)
self.As_of_Date.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("As_of_Date"))


@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def on_Go_clicked(self):
    AOD = self.As_of_Date.date()
    End_Date = AOD.toPyDate()
```

Below is a snapshot from the Renewals.py file

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt


def run_renewals():

    End_Date = pd.to_datetime(End_Date)
```

So basically in the Reports file, I have a pushbutton called Go. What I'd like for this to do is when it is pressed, it takes the as_of_date QdateEdit input, brings it into the Renewals file and runs the run_renewals function in the Renewals file.

I know my code is wrong but I'm confused as to where I should go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code already seems to do most of what you want. The main change is to add an argument to `run_renewals`:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

def run_renewals(end_date):
    # do stuff with end_date ...
```

Note that you don't need to use `pd.to_datetime` here, because `end_date` will already be a `datetime` object.

With that in place, the GUI file should look something like this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from Renewals import run_renewals
import pandas as pd
import sys

self.Go = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
self.Go.clicked.connect(self.on_Go_clicked)

self.As_of_Date = QtGui.QDateEdit(Form)

def on_Go_clicked(self):
    # this converts a QDate to a datetime object
    end_date = self.As_of_Date.date().toPyDate()
    run_renewals(end_date)
```

Comment: I knew I was close but didn't know I was that close. Thank you, it works!